# absolute_import not working correctly (in celery project)

Tags: python, import, celery

I am trying to setup a simple celery project. As per the [official documentation](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/next-steps.html#using-celery-in-your-application), the layout is as follow:

```
clemux@melody ~/dev/debian/debsources/debsources
% find new_updater -name "*.py" 
new_updater/tasks.py
new_updater/updater.py
new_updater/__init__.py
new_updater/celery.py
```

In celery.py, I import celery.Celery this way:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import Celery
```

In IPython, I can import new_updater.celery without problems:

```
In [2]: from debsources.new_updater import celery
In [3]: celery?
Type:        module
String form: <module 'debsources.new_updater.celery' from '/home/clemux/dev/debian/debsources/debsources/new_updater/celery.pyc'>
```

However, when trying to run new_updater.updater, I run into the following error:

```
clemux@melody ~/dev/debian/debsources
% python debsources/new_updater/updater.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "debsources/new_updater/updater.py", line 6, in <module>
    from debsources.new_updater.tasks import print_package
  File "/home/clemux/dev/debian/debsources/debsources/new_updater/tasks.py", line 3, in <module>
    from debsources.new_updater.celery import app
  File "/home/clemux/dev/debian/debsources/debsources/new_updater/celery.py", line 3, in <module>
    from celery import Celery
  File "/home/clemux/dev/debian/debsources/debsources/new_updater/celery.py", line 3, in <module>
    from celery import Celery
ImportError: cannot import name Celery
```

What could be going on here?

I know I could simply rename celery.py to, e.g. celery_config.py (this is the standard answer to this kind of question on SO), but I'd prefer actually fixing this and not stray away from celery's official documentation.

EDIT: I printed out `sys.path` in new_updater/updater.py, here's the result:

```
['/home/clemux/dev/debian/debsources/debsources/new_updater',
'/home/clemux/dev/debian/debsources',
'/home/clemux/.virtualenvs/debsources/lib/python2.7',
<snip>
```

Deleting `sys.path[0]` before the other import 'solves' the issue, but I don't understand why that is in the path. How I got that:

1. `mkvirtualenv test`
2. `python setup.py develop`  at the root of my project

EDIT2: it's the same outside a virtualenv, with celery installed from debian, and my `PYTHONPATH` set this way:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:~/dev/debian/debsources
```

Comment: did you try `PYTHONPATH=".:$PYTHONPATH" python debsources/new_updater/updater.py` ? also does `debsources/__init__.py` exist?

Comment: Just tried: it's the same. And yes.

Comment: Check this link this may solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19673662/import-error-in-celery

Comment: About how that first line got into sys.path: `A list of strings that specifies the search path for modules. Initialized from the environment variable PYTHONPATH, plus an installation-dependent default.

As initialized upon program startup, the first item of this list, path[0], is the directory containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter.` from https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html

Comment: Anyway, you shouldn't name your files as libraries you use, even if off. docs do so.

Comment: Thanks @pavel_form. Can you put this (the sys.path explication) in an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About how that first line got into `sys.path`:

> A list of strings that specifies the search path for modules.
>   Initialized from the environment variable PYTHONPATH, plus an
>   installation-dependent default. As initialized upon program startup,
>   the first item of this list, path[0], is the directory containing the
>   script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter.

from [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html)

Anyway, you shouldn't name your files as libraries you use, even if off. docs do so. Will help avoid many possible errors.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep it as "celery.py" because celery workers will find it automatically, but I will move my script ("updater.py") out of the module, since I shouldn't execute a script from a module anyway.